# generating function backtransformation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

i have been working with generating functions and i am fed up with always doing the partial fraction decomposition. i have found the following trick that can (hopefully) skip
pfd.

$$
\frac{z^j}{(1-z)^k} \iff \sum_{n\geq 0} \binom{n+k-1-j}{k-1} \cdot z^n
$$
i would like to prove it, however i seem to lack the skills to do so. can anyone confirm whether the proposed trick is actually valid?
thanks in advance

Comment: It is indeed true, and can be proved by many different ways, with arguably the easiest one using calculus: \begin{align*}\frac{z^j}{(1-z)^k}&=z^j\frac{\partial_z^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\frac{1}{1-z}\\&=z^j\frac{\partial_z^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}\sum_{n\geq 0}z^n\\&=z^j\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}z^{n-k+1}\end{align*} and rearranging the last sum (and re-indexing the summands) establishes the equivalence. If you prefer a combinatorial way, it will be fun to study read some basics about **combinatorial classes**, which provides a direct, combinatorial explanation to the equivalence you found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*. We use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}
\end{align*}

> Starting with the LHS we derive
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[z^n]\frac{z^j}{(1-z)^{k}}}&=[z^{n-j}]\frac{1}{(1-z)^k}
> =\binom{-k}{n-j}(-1)^{n-j}\tag{1}\\
> &=\binom{n-j+k-1}{n-j}\tag{2}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\binom{n-j+k-1}{k-1}}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$. We apply the binomial series expansion and select the coefficient $z^{n-j}$.
- In (2) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (3) we use $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.